# How to get Encryption key if i have data which needs to be encrypted is present and data after encryption is also present using DES

Tags: algorithm, security, encryption, des

I have a data which is encrypted using DES , it's a 10 character data which is encrypted into 28 character where last character is always = . I have around 10 data samples available. How can i get key to this.

Comment: With that little data, you're pretty much stuck with a brute-force attack (i.e., try one key after another until you find one that works). There are attacks (e.g., linear cryptanalysis) to find a key more quickly, but they require (a lot) more data than you're talking about.

Comment: Thanks Jerry ! Can you suggest me some tool for brute-force and linear cryptanalysis.

Comment: This question is offtopic cause it's not about programming. Try asking on http://crypto.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The "last character always =" sounds like the ciphertext is encoded in [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).  That's unrelated to the cryptography; you'll need to decode it to get the *real* ciphertext.

Answer (score 0):

You have too few samples for recover key. 10 samples is not seriously.

You need to collect 2^48 encrypted pairs (text:ciphertext) and 2^39 
attempts for recover key by linear cryptanalysis.

Detail here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Encryption_Standard